# Getting "Entity 'response_type' not defined" in ASP.NET web.config

Tags: web-config

Visual Studio is complaining about the following line in my web.config file:

```
<add key="foo" value="http://localhost?client_id=abc123&response_type=code&redirect_uri=google.com"/>
```

with the following errors:

```
"Entity 'response_type' not defined"
"Entity 'redirect_uri' not defined"
```

It says it expects a semi-colon where the equal signs are.

How can I escape this string so that it is treated as plain text?  I tried using an @ sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The & in the string is causing the error.**

To my horror the & is within my SMTP settings for my email password in System.Net. I came here in the hope to learn how to define the string or the &.